In the Abstract, do you summarize the whole invention or just an embodiment?
As I understand, the abstract can also be used by the examiner and court to limit your invention.
If that is the case, there is no reason to summarize the "invention" in the abstract, correct?
Just like in the detailed descriptions, you would summarize an "embodiment" of the invention, correct?

Obviously, to avoid limiting anything the abstract should be as general as possible. Take advantage of the fact that the abstract is not a claim and does not need to meet the requirements for claims. For example, it is not permitted to claim a functionality/result per se but I think the abstract should usually open with what the invention accomplishes. Then add some detail as to how it does that but stated more generally even than the main independent claim.

What is the purpose of the Abstract, anyways?

It gives the reader of the patent a vague idea of what the invention is.

The Patent Gazette still exists on line but was originally on paper as a weekly publication with the biographical information, abstract and front page drawing of all patents issued that week. Major libraries subscribed.  Like any other abstract it helps you decide quickly if a document is relevant to your needs.
